# i am not getting the desired result from mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

if i insert manualy in the table in database it shows the result in the grid but if i am entering from web page. it inserts in the database but not shoing in the result (grid in my page).

my query is

```
Declare paramfkVoucherType int(11);

SELECT ID INTO paramfkVoucherType 
FROM ListOfValues_AccountVoucherType
WHERE Name='Receipt Voucher';

SELECT 
        V.ID as VoucherID,
        V.Code as VoucherNumber,
        V.ToFrom As `From`,
        V.Amount as Amount,
        V.IsPosted as IsPosted,
        V.PostedDate as PostedDate,
        V.IsApproved as IsApproved,
        V.ApprovalDate as ApprovalDate,
        V.VoucherDate as VoucherDate,
        V.IsEdited as IsEdit,
        V.EditedDate as EditedDate,
        VT.Name as VoucherType,
        V.Description as Description,
        U.UserName As CreatedBy
FROM Account_Voucher V
INNER JOIN ListOfValues_AccountVoucherType VT ON V.fkVoucherTypeID = VT.ID
INNER JOIN usermanagement_user U ON U.ID =v.fkUserID
WHERE (V.fkVoucherTypeID = paramfkVoucherType)
      AND (V.Code like concat('%',spVoucherNumber,'%') OR spVoucherNumber='')
      AND (Date(V.VoucherDate) BETWEEN DATE(spFromDate) AND DATE(spToDate)
           OR DATE(spFromDate)='1/1/0001'
           OR DATE(spToDate)='1/1/0001')
      AND (U.ID =spfkEmployeeID OR  spfkEmployeeID=0)
      AND (V.IsDeleted=0)
      AND (VT.IsDeleted=0);
```

i want to show it on grid. it is a search query for voucher.

please help..

thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with your web page for entering data, not the query that extracts it.

Comment: the data is inserted in the database through the web page. i am just trying to retrieve it through search.

Comment: If the query finds the data when you enter it manually, but doesn't find it when you enter it through the web page, there must be something wrong with the web page. Or there's some difference in the data, and your query doesn't handle it properly. Without seeing the web page, there's no way for us to know what's different.

Comment: i cannot put image here as per my reputation factor but i do confirm you that my web page is inserting and filling all the data in the table but when i do the exact pattern manually it is showing in result otherwise invisible.

Comment: post your front end code

Comment: There _has_ to be some difference in the data. I don't know how you expect anyone to figure out what it is from what you've told us.

Comment: we need the web page information and your grid view code without that how you are expecting us to help, we need some data to reproduce the problem

Comment: this is my db connection code.

Comment: @skzac You can try and use imgur to link an image to your question, if you don't have reputation to upload images.

Comment: Done!! thanks alot for you guys.. the problem was, through the web page, it was entering USERID = null. thanks alot @Barmar

Comment: I hate to say "I told you so", but....

Comment: i am new.. so don't hate to say anything. :) thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a button that will refresh all your elements on your grid. Or a button that will update your elements on the grid once you add something on your page and once updated it should automatically refresh the grid so that your elements will be showed. Doing the adding of elements on the database manually is not a good practice.

Comment: i have already put a button for the search and it also refresh my page to retrieve the results from database.

Comment: the prob is that the manual data inserted is shown and when i insert the exact pattern data through page it is invisible in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query directly in mysql and see if inserted records are being fetched or not. If not, then inspect your inserted data, especially the fields used in query.